# Kickstarter Crowd Source Funding and PiTiVI

Tags: video, encoding

I have a video, generated in PiTiVi and cannot understand what to do with the rendering to make this video work on Kickstarter (KS). They say: "For video encoding, use WMV format in Windows. On Mac, use H.264." How do I get the PiTiVi rendering engine to make a .mov? There is no such option in the Rendering selections. The default formats of PiTiVi don't mention .mov or H.264. They do have a H.263.

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.PiTiVi 0.15.2.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.pitivi.org/manual/codecscontainers.html illustrates what they did not quite explain well at KickStarter: Please record using the H.264 codec and save the result within a .MOV container, said container will "contain" the various components of a video: the stream of images, the sound, and anything else.